# Running pipeline starting from another pipeline result

Tags: pipeline, go-cd

I need to create a pipeline to do unit and integrations tests and it will executed after lint pipeline on GO CD.

I've created a pipeline having as a material the previous pipeline (lint) but and the code is not available to the test pipeline. The test pipeline is automatically started when lint pipeline is successfully finished.

I have a git repository as a material on lint pipeline and it must be delivered to the next pipeline.

[image: Git Material Repository to Lint Pipeline]

[image: Test Pipeline Material from lint pipeline]

So I need test pipeline have the git repository from previous pipeline without cloning git again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your source code as an artifact from the lint pipeline and fetch it on the tests pipeline.

Having said that I recommend to have both the tasks as part of the same pipeline, as different stages may be? In my personal experience I've always seen configuring pipelines based on the set of materials that operate together has helped me design my flows more effectively.